# Store data series in file or database if I want to do row level math operations?

Tags: python, database, database-design, file-io

I'm developing an app that handle sets of financial series data (input as csv or open document), one set could be say 10's x 1000's up to double precision numbers (Simplifying, but thats what matters).

I plan to do operations on that data (eg. sum, difference, averages etc.) as well including generation of say another column based on computations on the input. This will be between columns (row level operations) on one set and also between columns on many (potentially all) sets at the row level also. I plan to write it in Python and it will eventually need a intranet facing interface to display the results/graphs etc. for now, csv output based on some input parameters will suffice.

What is the best way to store the data and manipulate? So far I see my choices as being either (1) to write csv files to disk and trawl through them to do the math or (2) I could put them into a database and rely on the database to handle the math. My main concern is speed/performance as the number of datasets grows as there will be inter-dataset row level math that needs to be done.

-Has anyone had experience going down either path and what are the pitfalls/gotchas that I should be aware of?

-What are the reasons why one should be chosen over another? 

-Are there any potential speed/performance pitfalls/boosts that I need to be aware of before I start that could influence the design?

-Is there any project or framework out there to help with this type of task?

-Edit-
More info:
The rows will all read all in order, BUT I may need to do some resampling/interpolation to match the differing input lengths as well as differing timestamps for each row. Since each dataset will always have a differing length that is not fixed, I'll have some scratch table/memory somewhere to hold the interpolated/resampled versions. I'm not sure if it makes more sense to try to store this (and try to upsample/interploate to a common higher length) or just regenerate it each time its needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"I plan to do operations on that data (eg. sum, difference, averages etc.) as well including generation of say another column based on computations on the input."**

This is the standard use case for a data warehouse star-schema design.  Buy Kimball's The Data Warehouse Toolkit.  Read (and understand) the star schema before doing anything else.

**"What is the best way to store the data and manipulate?**"

A Star Schema.

You can implement this as flat files (CSV is fine) or RDBMS.  If you use flat files, you write simple loops to do the math.  If you use an RDBMS you write simple SQL *and* simple loops.

**"My main concern is speed/performance as the number of datasets grows"**

Nothing is as fast as a flat file.  Period.  RDBMS is slower.

The RDBMS value proposition stems from SQL being a relatively simple way to specify `SELECT SUM(), COUNT() FROM fact JOIN dimension WHERE filter GROUP BY dimension attribute`.  Python isn't as terse as SQL, but it's just as fast and just as flexible.  Python competes against SQL.

**"pitfalls/gotchas that I should be aware of?"**

DB design.  If you don't get the star schema and how to separate facts from dimensions, all approaches are doomed.  Once you separate facts from dimensions, all approaches are approximately equal.

**"What are the reasons why one should be chosen over another?"**

RDBMS slow and flexible.  Flat files fast and (sometimes) less flexible.  Python levels the playing field.

**"Are there any potential speed/performance pitfalls/boosts that I need to be aware of before I start that could influence the design?"**

Star Schema:  central fact table surrounded by dimension tables.  Nothing beats it.

**"Is there any project or framework out there to help with this type of task?"**

Not really.

Answer (score 1):

For speed optimization, I would suggest two other avenues of investigation beyond changing your underlying storage mechanism:

**1) Use an intermediate data structure.**

If maximizing speed is more important than minimizing memory usage, you may get good results out of using a different data structure as the basis of your calculations, rather than focusing on the underlying storage mechanism. This is a strategy that, in practice, has reduced runtime in projects I've worked on dramatically, regardless of whether the data was stored in a database or text (in my case, XML).

While sums and averages will require runtime in only [O(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), more complex calculations could easily push that into O(n^2) without applying this strategy. O(n^2) would be a performance hit that would likely have far more of a perceived speed impact than whether you're reading from CSV or a database. An example case would be if your data rows reference other data rows, and there's a need to aggregate data based on those references.

So if you find yourself doing calculations more complex than a sum or an average, you might explore data structures that can be created in O(n) and would keep your calculation operations in O(n) or better. As Martin pointed out, it sounds like your whole data sets can be held in memory comfortably, so this may yield some big wins. What kind of data structure you'd create would be dependent on the nature of the calculation you're doing.

**2) Pre-cache.**

Depending on how the data is to be used, you could store the calculated values ahead of time. As soon as the data is produced/loaded, perform your sums, averages, etc., and store those aggregations alongside your original data, or hold them in memory as long as your program runs. If this strategy is applicable to your project (i.e. if the users aren't coming up with unforeseen calculation requests on the fly), reading the data shouldn't be prohibitively long-running, whether the data comes from text or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you likely to need all rows in order or will you want only specific known rows?
If you need to read all the data there isn't much advantage to having it in a database.

edit: If the code fits in memory then a simple CSV is fine. Plain text data formats are always easier to deal with than opaque ones if you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

What matters most if all data will fit simultaneously into memory. From the size that you give, it seems that this is easily the case (a few megabytes at worst).

If so, I would discourage using a relational database, and do all operations directly in Python. Depending on what other processing you need, I would probably rather use binary pickles, than CSV.

Comment: Yes it will fit in memory, even at a real worst case some 10's of MB I think. Could you elaborate why you would pick binary pickles over CSV?  What sort of processing would dictate choosing a specific one?

Comment: Pickles are the simpler programming model. For CSV, you need to map the data into proper container structures (possibly changing how the csv module provides them); with pickles, you can always have the data arranged in the structures that you need for processing.